# Play Framework 2.6 Evolutions not working when using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

Hi I recently migrated from Ebeans to Hibernate and suddenly Play's Database Evolutions are not working anymore. I have disabled hibarnate ddl creation like this in my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My application.conf looks like this

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ConfigFile


# Point JPA at our database configuration
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

# Number of database connections
# See https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing
fixedConnectionPool = 9

play.http.secret.key="RJr?nE5jHzAXtqvvnB6^pe0sQUGQX4@0df^Qlsev2EEEA43z0HfS6sz1?uob?b5]"

db.default {
  driver = org.postgresql.Driver
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.155.177/legato"
  username = "vagrant"
  password = "vagrant"
  jndiName = DefaultDS
}

applyEvolutions.default=true

# disable the built in filters
play.http.filters = play.api.http.NoHttpFilters

# Job queue sized to HikariCP connection pool
post.repository {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  throughput = 1
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = ${fixedConnectionPool}
  }
}
```

The behaviour is that hibernate is correctly not generating the database however Play will also not generate any evolutions scripts whatsoever. If I start up the App in Development Mode it will work and throw a PersistenceException whenever the Database is queried, as no table exits.

Could anybody help me out here?

Comment: `applyEvolutions.default` configuration [was deprecated in Play 2.4](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Configuration-changes) and I can't see it in Play 2.6 anymore. You need to use 
`play.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true` as [documented here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Evolutions#Evolutions-configuration).

Comment: Also, it could be good to edit the question to add the stack trace.